# Puilling Information From Referenced Entities to Display/Use In A Custom Content Type?

Tags: nodes, entities

## Exposition

I have two Content Types with the following fields:

- Scenes

  1. Scene Name
  2. Starring (Actor's names)
  3. Streaming Link
- Releases (DVD Releases)

  1. Title
  2. Description
  3. *Starring* (All actor's names from all Scenes referenced)
  4. Scenes (Entity references to the Scene Content Type)

## My question

When displaying a Release node, how can I get Drupal to generate the list of Starring Actors by taking the names from the 'Starring' fields in the Scene nodes that have been referenced?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions

First, the most common solution:

1. Create a [View](http://drupal.org/project/views)
2. Add a "relationship" from Release to Stars
3. Add whatever fields you want to display, in this case, "Name", and make they "Use relationship Stars".

Second, what I would have done:

1. Create a suitable [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) [Page](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) for Releases
2. Create a mini-panel for Stars
3. Add the Stars reference field to the releases page with "[Panels reference formatter](http://drupal.org/project/panels_ref_formatter)", choose the mini-panel as the formatter.

[Intro to Views](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone).

[Intro to Page manager and Panels](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager).